# MacOS Ventura Apps do not ask for permissions after tccutil reset

Tags: permission, microphone, ventura

A similar question to [olzpaul's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457235/tccutil-reset-all-breaks-permissions) but in this case, I have some, not all, SIP features disabled (see below), though I don't believe this has anything to do with the problem at hand. (WRT SIP, I understand the risks and this question is not an invitation to debate its merits.)

Some time ago, I installed a chat app (Telegram) on which I didn't expect to use voice comms, so I did not allow it permissions to access my microphone at the time.  Yesterday, though, I needed to use the microphone with it, but Telegram was not listed in the *Privacy & Security -> Microphone* list, so I was not able to flip the slider switch to enable it.

After trying some things to make Telegram ask for permissions, including restarting it, I decided to see how others dealt with this issue by searching the web. Amongst the advice I saw was a reference to a utility called `tccutil` where it was suggested to use the command: `tccutil reset Microphone`.  It was explained that the command would reset all the permissions for the microphone and therefore force apps to ask for permissions again.  So I executed this command in my terminal and saw that the entire Microphone permissions list was scrubbed.  I didn't think much of this as it's essentially what I was expecting to happen.

However, when I relaunched Telegram, I was not prompted with a permission request.  I found this a bit strange and tried some of my other chat apps with which I use the microphone regularly; namely Discord and MS Teams.  To my dismay, they did not ask me for permission to access my microphone, thus, as things stand right now, I am unable to use my microphone on my computer.

How can this problem be solved?  Is there some command(s) or places in *System Settings* which allow the owner/administrator to manage these settings?  Alternatively, is there some documentation that explains how to manually manage the privacy database that `tccutil` reset?

I have seen some advice on this issue, to do with League of Legends (which I don't play), but in that case the problem was that that user's client wasn't coded to ask for permissions in the first place, so the permission needed to be manually given.  I don't mind doing this, but it appeared to me that some detail information was needed to enable this which I am unsure of how to find/determine.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: unknown (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
    Apple Internal: disabled
    Kext Signing: disabled
    Filesystem Protections: disabled
    Debugging Restrictions: enabled
    DTrace Restrictions: enabled
    NVRAM Protections: enabled
    BaseSystem Verification: enabled

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.
```

Comment: Links for sidebar - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387068/upgrading-catalina-on-non-supported-hardware-fails-with-install-macos-catalina and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342710/reset-all-mojave-app-permissions

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to use (*carefully, as per the author's own comments*) the tool `tccplus` that can be found at https://github.com/jslegendre/tccplus

The app needs to be built before you can use it, so you will need Xcode, LLVM, etc.  After that, it's a two-step process:

```
grep 'BundleIdent' -A 1 /Applications/<APPLICATION>/Contents/Info.plist
tccplus add Microphone <bundle_ID>
```

Use `grep` to find the `CFBundleIdentifier` for the app. And then use the reverse domain name with `tccplus`.
There are various other things you can do with `tccplus` so, run it without parameters and it will tell you.

You might need to find the location where Xcode puts the compiled binary, `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tccplus-...../Build/Products/Debug/` is a good place to start looking for it.

I was able to resolve my problem without having to make any SIP changes.  (*One of the reasons for the caveat in my OP.  SIP is often a judgemental magnet to Mac users like `root` is in the linux community.*)

Acknowledgement: I found out about `tccplus` in one of the answers (don't know how to link to it directly) to a similar question at the Super User stack: https://superuser.com/questions/1779925/macos-ventura-cant-give-permissions-opencore . @Tetsujin's sidebar comment to my OP mentions a couple other places where information about `tccplus` has been discussed.

Answer (score -1):

Since TCC permissions are inherited, in one-off situations, you could try granting the permission you need to Terminal and open your desired app from Terminal instead. Or you could write a one-liner apple script to open that app and hope that it'd ask for the permission you're looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).